# React-native-splashscreen and navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-navigation-stack

I want to create a splashscreen without the whitescreen issue using the react-native splash screen and after that I want to check the navigation. Suppose I got 3 screen Splash, Login and Home. If the user is logged in I want to navigate to the Home screen from the Splash screen otherwise I want to navigate it to the Login page from the Splash screen. How do I achieve this using react-native-splash-screen and react-navigation.

> App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {SafeAreaProvider} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/es/integration/react';
import Navigator from './app/navigation/NavigationStack';
import configureStore from './app/store/configureStore';
const {persistor, store} = configureStore();
export default function App() {
 return (
  <SafeAreaProvider>
   <Provider store={store}>
     <PersistGate loading={<ActivityIndicator />} persistor={persistor}>
       <Navigator></Navigator>
     </PersistGate>
   </Provider>
  </SafeAreaProvider>
 );
}
```

> NavigationStack.js

```
function MyStack() {
 return (
  <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
   <Stack.Navigator
     screenOptions={{
       headerShown: false,
     }}>
     <Stack.Screen
       name={Strings.string_SignInScreen}
       component={SignInScreen}
     />
     <Stack.Screen name={Strings.string_HomeScreen} component={Home} />

  </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
 );
}
export default MyStack;
```

Comment: Refer to React-native-splash-screen module for resolution.

Comment: Referred still didnt get the naswer

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaKqek_m2mI They have explained proper steps for achieve your goal.

Comment: No it doesn't , please read the question. There's a condition I need to check

Comment: @VinayN  how did you solve it?

Comment: @SimaAmini Well I followed the official navigation doc itself for authentication(https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/#define-our-screens) and then navigation. The white screen issue, well it solved somehow here in my case. You can either use react-native-splash-screen or react-native-boot-splash for handling that case. Checkout this link for clarification https://blog.logrocket.com/splash-screen-react-native/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,in its componentDidMount cehck fro user exits via asyncstorage etc, and then navigate accordingly

```
 import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen'

    export default class WelcomePage extends Component {

        componentDidMount() {
            // do stuff while splash screen is shown
            // After having done stuff (such as async tasks) hide the splash screen

if(userExists){
 SplashScreen.hide();
this.props.navigation.navigate('Homescreen');
} else {
this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreen');
}

        }
    }
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: hey Gourav could you please share your mail id ?

Comment: Here in the WelcomePage what about the render() { return () } function ?

Comment: no render, you dont want to render, just have the logic

Comment: I've added my App.js file and navigation stack. Please have a look at it